# Redirecting to another form in CRM 4.0 based on entity type

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4

In CRM 4.0, how can I, upon double-clicking on a record in the view grid (when it opens in edit form), check the record's Type attribute and redirect to another entity's edit page (depending on type) by passing a shared ID attribute called Document ID?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish - I have a main entity called Transaction, but it's the abstract type and by itself it is not editable - like Activities in CRM. There are specific types of Transaction entities such as Customer Pricing - these entities ARE editable (like the entity named Fax or Email in Activities). The entity called Transaction shares a number of common attributes with its sub types, including one called Document ID. When double-clicking on a Transaction record, I need to redirect the user to the corresponding entity's edit page.

Comment: You could do this with some javascript on the Transaction form OnLoad - what value is held in the Document ID field? To do the redirect you would need the sub type ID (guid) and sub type ObjectTypeCode.

Comment: Assume I have that - but what's the code that will redirect based on the sub type id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you could do this via some javascript that runs on the form's OnLoad event.

My understanding:

- User clicks on 'Transaction' entity Entity form loads
- On the screen for that entity there are two fields:

  - one field called 'Document ID' which holds the Id of the sub type
  - another field called 'Document ID Type' which holds the ObjectTypeCode of the sub type

My CRM4 is a bit hazy as I have been working with CRM2011 recently but something like this would work.

```js
function OnLoad {
    //let's look for the type field
    var typeValue = crmForm.all.new_documentid.Value;
    var typeObjectTypeCode = crmForm.all.new_documentidtypecode.Value;
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/';
    url = url + 'userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=' + typeObjectTypecode + '&id=' + typeValue;

    var newWindowHandle = window.open(url);

    //optionally close this window
    window.top.close();
}
```

URLs to open custom entities taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx)